# Warped meshes when exporting to glTF

Tags: gltf

I am exporting to *glTF* and some of the geometries are distorted. In a previous post I pointed out that I need to apply all the modifiers and transformations. (Converted to mesh and pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to apply the transformations).

Everything is already a mesh, and I have no problems with the materials. Something in the position/rotation/transformation data gets messed up along the way. I imported images as layers and they ended up further away from their location. I saw this with another mesh I downloaded from Blendswap - the planes were rotated.

Yes, I can file a bug, but does anyone know if there is a way to "reset" all the data for the warped/rotated parts or delete old incorrect data that is exported?

How it should look:

[image]

How it's warping:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay so while I don't know what the problem was to begin with, I'm sure others have logged this. What worked for me right now was joining the warped/skewed meshes to the one main mesh that wasn't warped. I did this one at a time.  Outcome is satisfactory:

[image]