# Mesh exporting warped in .glb format

Tags: mesh

I am relatively new to Blender, but managed to tutorial my way into making my first model. For the export I am using .glb format, but running into an issue of the mesh stretching/warping when doing a test, as seen below.

[image]

The closet thing to a solution I found was parenting the objects together to the unwarped object (the body), as suggested by this post: [Warped meshes when exporting to glTF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279988/warped-meshes-when-exporting-to-gltf)

The problem I ran into with that was two fold. One each main object has it's own animation, and parenting them together seems to negative the individual animation to just match the main object. Also, the model now has a second wing that does not appear in the file itself.

[image]

Any suggestions for where I can begin to correct these formatting issues would be greatly appreciated. If more information is needed, just let me know.

Thanks and appreciated!